# Обрезать строку до третьего вхождения символа

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка

```
String str = "/tmp/junit1214541221/SS_table_1.dat"
```

Как обрезать ее до третьего вхождения символа /, включая его? Результат должен быть такой

```
String res = "SS_table_1.dat"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же просто имя файла извлечь надо, может образка нужна не до третьего а до последнего символа?

```
    String str = "/tmp/junit1214541221/SS_table_1.dat";
    String res1 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/'));
    System.out.println("res1 = " + res1);
```

Вот через `split`

```
    String[] splitted = str.split("/");
    String res2 = '/' + splitted[splitted.length-1];
    System.out.println("res2 = " + res2);
```

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Вот нормальный способ:

```
String result = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";
System.out.println(result.substring(result.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316487/java-getting-a-substring-from-a-string-starting-after-a-particular-character)

Способ конечно костыльный...

1. Переворачиваем строку:  `res = new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString();`
2. Обрезаем строку: `res = res.substring(0, result.indexOf('/'));`
3. Переворачиваем строку обратно: `res = new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString();`

Итого:

```
res = new StringBuffer(new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString().substring(0, result.indexOf('/')).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: `result.lastIndexOf("/") + 1` неа, автор хотел включать `/`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ аа, ок, спасибо)

Comment: Утешительный приз держи =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ;)